# Maximum height of inline object that does not alter interline

Tags: tex-core, baseline

I would like to know what's the maximum height of an object that does not mess with the interline.

I naively thought that if my object height is `\baselineskip` everything would have looked alright, but that's not the case.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{minimal}
\usepackage{printlen}\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newlength\h \h=\baselineskip

\textcolor{cyan}{
Writing some\\
text over\\
multiple lines.}

Writing some \tikz[baseline=\h/3]{\draw (0,0) rectangle (\h,\h);}\\
text over \tikz[baseline=\h/3]{\draw (0,0) rectangle (\h,\h);}\\
multiple lines.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the square on the first line is missing, the interline is not messed up.
I'm certain this question is a duplicate, but I had no success with using the search functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of one line plus the depth of the line above needs to be less than `\baselineskip`.

So it is sufficient (but not necessary) to ensure the height of all lines is at most .7\baselineskip and depth .3\baselineskip.  or `\ht\strutbox` and `\dp\strutbox`

your test file has

```
...\hbox(8.2+4.2)x469.75499, glue set 395.60489fil
...\penalty 150
...\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
...\hbox(8.2+4.2)x469.75499, glue set 415.10493fil
```

with `(\lineskip)` flagging that `\baselineskip` is not maintained.

Depth of first line + height of second = 4.2pt + 8.2pt = 12.4pt > 12pt = \baselineskip

Comment: Note your test boxes have `\baselineskip` (12pt) between the coordinates of the horizontal rules, but those rules have thickness so you end up being 0.4pt too big

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have so many questions, though… `\strutbox` seems to be the character ﬀ. What are `\ht\strutbox` and `\dp\strutbox`? Why check the height and depth of ﬀ? Also, what is the code starting with … that you're showing? The only bit I understand is the last sentence 

Comment: Could you address my doubts?

Comment: `\strutbox` is a zero width rule `\ht` gives its height above the baseline `\dp` gives its depth below the baseline, these by convention add up to baselineskip.  The output I show is from the log if you add `\showoutput` it is a symbolic represention of the output so you do not have to look at the pdf and guess if lines are equally spaced, tex will report the exact lengths used. @Atcold

Comment: I see, thanks. I'm still confused about `\strutbox`. If I type that in a `tex` file it is rendered as the double-f character.

Comment: @Atcold that is just user error (I wondered why you mentioned ff:-)  `\strutbox` is a box register defined by `\newbox\strutbox`  so actually if you use it directly it is just a number and makes the character from the current font that has that number the  intended use is `\strut` which dos `\copy\strutbox` and puts a copy of the strut into the text.